# javascript page element access from one child iframe to another child

Tags: javascript, iframe

I´m trying to access a few elements from a child iframe to another...

I´ve tried to reference childNodes with no luck (alert 0):

```
alert(window.parent.document.getElementById('framechildidonparent').childNodes.length);
```

Also tried to go upward to parent and then down to child with no luck:

```
function getParentFrameProperties(idframe,idobject){
  var myframe = window.parent.document.getElementById(idframe).contentWindow;
  var insideobject = myframe.document.getElementById(idobject).value;
  alert(insideobject);
}
```

Any clues? Thanks in advance.

Comment: So basically you want to *communicate* between two iframes within a parent page. Where did you put your alert?

Comment: yeap! My parent has three child iframes. In one of the child I´ve manage to reload the other iframe and pass get parameters (setAttribute src) but now I need access to various elements from another child

Comment: Iframes are asyncronous. Means that one iframe might *load* before another does. You could `postMessage` events trough your iframes using the parent as mediator.

Comment: could you elaborate an example retrieving element value of child a from child b?

Answer (score 2):

### Retrieve Element value from other iframe:

This is your parent element:

```
<iframe src="iframe1.html"></iframe>
<iframe src="iframe2.html"></iframe>
```

And this is your input in iframe1.html:

```
<input id="inp" value="HELLO!!!">
```

Let's retrieve it's value in iframe2.html:

```
parent.window.onload = function(){

    var ifr1     = parent.document.getElementById("ifr1");
    var ifr1_DOC = ifr1.contentDocument || ifr1.contentWindow.document;
    
    console.log( ifr1_DOC.getElementById("inp").value ); // "HELLO!!!"

}
```

---

### Live communicating between iframes:

Pseudo:

```
iframe1 >>> postMessage to window.parent
iframe2 >>> addEventListener to window.parent that will listen for postMessage events
```

This is your **parent** element:

```
<iframe src="iframe1.html"></iframe>
<iframe src="iframe2.html"></iframe>
```

Example: `iframe1 >>> sends data to >>> iframe2`

**Iframe1: (sends)**

```
<script>
var n = 0;
function postToParent(){
    el.innerHTML = n;
    // IMPORTANT: never use "*" but yourdomain.com address.
    parent.postMessage(n++, "*");
}
setInterval(postToParent, 1000);
</script>
```

**Iframe2: (receives)**

```
<p id="el">NUMBER CHANGES HERE</p>

<script>
var el = document.getElementById("el");
function receiveMessage(event) {
    // Do we trust the sender of this message?
    // IMPORTANT! Uncomment the line below and set yourdomain.com address.
    // if (event.origin !== "yourdomain.com") return;
    el.innerHTML = event.data;
}
parent.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
</script>
```

You should see in iframe2 the `p` element increase numbers that are sent from iframe1.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: nothing happens... I tried even adapt my previous onclick attempt to your example but nothing is fired:    function getParentFrameProperties(idframe,idobject){

    var ifr1     = parent.document.getElementById(idframe);
    var ifr1_DOC = ifr1.contentDocument || ifr1.contentWindow.document;

    alert( ifr1_DOC.getElementById(idobject).value ); // idobject value

}

Comment: @MarceloJuniorCarvalho it should work. I've tested it. Make sure that your `<script>` tags are right before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: worth to say the architecture uses nested iframes and the parent in this case isn´t the topmost...

Comment: Would help to see a graph depicting the parent relations you need.

Comment: seems like my function will need a case or if statement...I tested over controlled scenario with one embed iframe or more...the nested degree is nt static as depends on user selection of inner functionalities on page.

Comment: Seems like you're creating an app where every iframe module adds some functionality to the application? You need to wrap your head around a functionality to get the outermost parent. Or to make all your iframes be notified of `set` and `get` *messages* between them.